# Remove underline from AutoCompleteTextView via xml

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

i have this view:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rect_search"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rect_search"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rect_search"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rect_search"
        android:hint="@string/search_bar"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

as you can see, this view goes inside another view, rect_search, that is an ImageView. 
Now i've noticed that AutoCompleteTextView widget has a default underline on bottom, and i would remove it. It's possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just put:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

inside your view.

EDIT: As @kiya said, nowadays is better to use

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

As it maintains the view size.

Comment: If you want to maintain the size of your view, use android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 3):

android:inputType="textPhonetic"

Comment: Please expand your answer by giving some more details about your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work properly

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below if you want to remove the underline and maintain the size:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made many tries to build up a drop-down with the correct color and focus material-looking options with rounded corners.

I will share it to help others and the result would be something like this:
In non-focused mode:
[image]

In focused-mode and drop-down activated:

[image]

The only issue at the moment is if somebody can focus the dropdown in some way (e.g. using TAB button on the keyboard), he/she can type inside the textbox but in touch mode, there would be no issues
Here is the XML which should be used in the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/CustomDropDownLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="18dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="18dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="18dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="18dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
        >


    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:background="@drawable/drop_down_background"
            android:id="@+id/userNameDropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

put the custom style inside: `res\values\customstyles.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>



    <style name="CustomDropDownLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
        <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHelperStyle</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutErrorStyle</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHintStyle</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_dropdown_box_color</item>
    </style>



    <style name="TextInputLayoutErrorStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/myfont.ttf</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextInputLayoutHintStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/myfont.ttf</item>

    </style>

    <style name="TextInputLayoutHelperStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
        <item name="fontPath">fonts/myfont.ttf</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_layout_not_focused</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

And put this color inside a single file such as `res\color\text_input_layout_dropdown_box_color.xml`:

And also another file named `\res\color\text_input_layout_dropdown_hint_color.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_hovered="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/input_layout_not_focused" />  <!-- unfocused -->
</selector>
```

And put a file among drawables `res\drawable\drop_down_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners
            android:radius="20dp" />
    <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/text_input_layout_dropdown_hint_color" />

</shape>
```

And use a custom adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter dropDownAdpater = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, users);
userNameDropDownMenuAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(dropDownAdpater);
//set first item as selected one
if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
    userNameDropDownMenuAutoCompleteTextView.setText(dropDownAdpater.getItem(0).toString(), false);
}
userNameDropDownMenuAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_down_background);
userNameDropDownMenuAutoCompleteTextView.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
    userNameDropDownMenuAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
    return true;
});
```

And at last add a file among layouts in a file `res\layout\dropdown_menu_popup_item.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below if you want to remove the underline and maintain the size: app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"

=><com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

```
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"

    android:layout_width="345dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
    app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
      android:scrollIndicators="none"
     app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/people"
    app:startIconTint="@color/btnbackground">

    <AutoCompleteTextView

        android:id="@+id/autotext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corner_border"

        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/darkbringle" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```